# swift uitapgesturerecognizer pass parameters

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a lot of Buttons created programmatically and that can change anytime. my tap gesture :

```
let apriVideoGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PrincipaleController.apriVideo(_:)))
cont.addGestureRecognizer(apriVideoGesture)

func apriVideo(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){

}
```

how can i pass parameters? somethig like this :

```
let apriVideoGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PrincipaleController.apriVideo(stringa : "ciao")))
cont.addGestureRecognizer(apriVideoGesture)

func apriVideo(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer, stringa : String){

}
```

sorry for bad english, i'm italian

Comment: No you cant, but tell me the purpose of passing such, so that i can tell you some alternatives

Comment: i need to pass a string with the URL. the page is created in base of some articles recived by the server and i need to open the specific page in base of the container pressed

Comment: Alex let me reach home, I'll do that for you  for sure

Comment: thanks a lot , I'm desperate

Comment: Can u plz show me what type of view u want to create, this is how I can get idea

Comment: As far as I understand your need, I'll suggest you to use `UITableView`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, if you are using button then why are you adding tap gesture? You can add target to it as

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDragInside)
```

**But still you can achieve you goal using tap gesture as**

Using UIView as u have insisted

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let arrayOfSongsURL: [String] = []
    let startingTag = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let height : CGFloat = 100
        let width : CGFloat = 100
        (arrayOfSongsURL as NSArray).enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (url, index, finished) -> Void in
            
            let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(index) * height, width, height))
            v.tag = self.startingTag + index
            
            v.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapGesture(_:))))
            self.view.addSubview(v)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    
    
    @objc func handleTapGesture(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let v = gesture.view!
        let tag = v.tag
        let songURL = arrayOfSongsURL[tag - startingTag]
        
        //Do what you want to do with songURL
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do it also with UIVIew?

Comment: Yes you can do with UIView with TapGesture, you can not add target to UIView as i've shown

Comment: What you dont understand?

Comment: how can i do it without "add target" of the button. Because i use only UIView

Comment: Then you can go with `UITapGesture` na, but you have mentioned that u are using the button so i suggest

Comment: is the .tag the only way tho? can you put entire object into it?

Comment: You can subclass the View and make a variable which can store the url and access the same